# How to handle soft Keyboard show/events in whole app

Tags: android, scroll, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

1:-I wanna handle handle show/hide events of softkeyboard dat i wanna hide soft keyboard if user on any other widget excepti edittext and user scrolls in app.

Please tell me how hide the keyboard in app.

2:- Is that possible to handle keyboard at one place and apply to all activity in application.

please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

this method use for hide our softkeyboard:

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: how should i  do that means to handle keyboard at one place apply to all activities in app

Answer (score 0):

You should read about the InputMethodManager @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html

To get a grip on the APIs.

There are APIs to show and hide